# AS3 URLRequest POST sometimes gets turned into a GET request

Tags: php, .htaccess, actionscript-3

Our users can uploads files to our sever using URLRequest POST method from Flash AS3 to PHP then to our web server. We have recently discovered in our LOG files that some browsers change the POST request into a GET request rendering the upload of a file useless.

We're not sure what is going on here. Here is the code we use:
AS3

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest;
        request.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache"));
        request = new URLRequest ("http://www.domain.com/uploads/uploader.php");
        request.data = variables;
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
```

PHP

```
<?php
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
if($_POST['count'] == 0){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], 'temp/'.$_POST['folderString'].'/dateiVorne/'.$filename);
}
if($_POST['count'] == 1){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], 'temp/'.$_POST['folderString'].'/dateiHinten/'.$filename);
}
?>
```

.htaccess

```
# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And why do you think that is an htaccess related issue?

Comment: I thought maybe the htaccess rewrite could be turing the POST into GET. Just a hunch that's why I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be this:

> If running in Flash Player and the referenced form has no body, Flash
>   Player automatically uses a GET operation, even if the method is set
>   to URLRequestMethod.POST. For this reason, it is recommended to always
>   include a "dummy" body to ensure that the correct method is used.

[From documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#method)

I suggest you always to include dummy URLVariable like new URLVariables("v=0");

Check this [link](http://lindensgarden.blogspot.com/2010/01/flashneturlloader-will-change-your.html)

Comment: I'm not too sure what a dummy body looks like. Would this be a a simple Form within a Body Tag in the PHP uploader?

Comment: I have same question like @BobbySolo what is a dummy body and how can I add it to my form? do you mean in flash? or...?

Comment: @AzzyElvul my URLVariables is obviously not empty. because I want this variables to be sent as POST and they are sent as GET and I can see them in url. `var vars: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
   var points:String = parsData();
   vars.data   = JSON.stringify(this.clickSequence + "**" + points);
   
   var req: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/graph/index.php/user/info");
   req.method      = "POST";/*URLRequestMethod.POST;*/
   req.data        = vars;
   
   navigateToURL(req, "_self");`